# How to integrate react-router's navigate in a generic and robust UD fetch implementation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I'm attempting to write a reusable robust fetch implementation that will automatically redirect to an error page upon any exception including a bit of context in the props `errorMessage`. I'd like to streamline and eliminate all boilerplate code throughout my codebase. To this end, I'm currently attempting:

```
export const myFetch = async (requestUrl, navigate=undefined, {method, body}={}) => {
    method = method == undefined ? 'GET' : method;
    let config = {method, headers: {'Accept', 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}};
    if (method === 'POST') {
        config = {...config, body: JSON.stringify(body)};
    }

    try {
        const response = await fetch(requestUrl, config);
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`${response.status}: ${response.statusText}`)
        }
        const json = await response.json();
        return json;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(`ERROR: ${error.message}`;
        navigate && navigate('/error', {
            state: {
                errorMessage: error.message
            }
        });
    } 
}
```

then I attempt to use it from a component as follows:

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

const MyComponent = (props) => {
    const nagivate = useNavigate(); 

    useEffect(() => {
        myFetch('/some/bad/url', navigate).then(data => ...);
    }, []);
};
```

but this is not working as the `then` step executes and the data is invalid ...

Comment: `throw error` to ensure the consumer _doesn't_ get a resolving promise? Right now it's implicitly resolving to undefined.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks indeed but then the navigate will be lost or?